# column r.user_id not found in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find all the IP counts the customer and our clients have in common from various different tables. I know that in a subquery the inner most query can't access the outer most query, but I'm not sure how to join the tables to get around that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugEJM.jpg

The table orders is reviews, company_user_role, previous_state_transitions

```
SELECT 
r.id, r.state,

(SELECT count(dog.ip_address)

FROM

(SELECT DISTINCT ip_address COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS ip_address
FROM previous_state_transitions
WHERE user_id = r.user_id

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT ip_address COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS ip_address
FROM previous_state_transitions
WHERE state_machineable_id = r.user_id
AND state_machineable_type = "User"

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT ip_address
FROM reviews 
WHERE user_id = r.user_id) AS dog

INNER JOIN

(SELECT DISTINCT ip_address COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS ip_address
FROM previous_state_transitions
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM company_user_roles WHERE company_id = r.company_id)

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT ip_address COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS ip_address
FROM previous_state_transitions
WHERE state_machineable_id = (SELECT user_id FROM company_user_roles WHERE company_id = r.company_id)
AND state_machineable_type = "User"

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT ip_address
FROM reviews 
WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM company_user_roles WHERE company_id = r.company_id)) AS cat

ON dog.ip_address = cat.ip_address) AS ip_count_in_common

FROM reviews AS r
WHERE r.created_at > '2016-10-13'
ORDER BY 1 desc
```

Comment: I started editing your post, then abandoned it when I realized that you have a query with 4 nested layers.  I suspect that there is an easier way to get the information you want.  Maybe you could show us sample data along with what you want to extract.

Comment: Overall, it looks pretty close to a runnable query.  There are two instances in your "cat" subquery that need fixing.  That subquery has 3 parts UNIONed together - in the first part you have `where user_id IN ` (correct), but in the second and third you have `=`, and you need to use `IN` in those two parts as well.

Comment: The entirety of the inner query works, it's just that when I put it under another layer that it won't work.  The issue isn't the "=" operator because its just another way to filter the same table for information not in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you use the data in the result `r` before it is defined.

In other words: you cannot reference the end-result `r` in the definition that makes up `r`.

What you should do is start with each sub-query and see whether the code works on it's own. When it does not - as in any case where `r` is referenced - you need to think up a different solution, e.g. returning the user_id in the output.

Sorry that I can only give you a method to solve the problem, not the solution itself. Like Tim I tried to edit the query for you, but it is too long and I would need to know the whole data structure to know the best solution.

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Comment: All the subquery code works by itself, I'll try to provide a sample of the database later.

Comment: By itself I mean that your main union statements should work by themselves. That is: they should not reference any data in r and you cannot put in those references later because that breaks your code..